# AWS S3 Lifecycle Rule - Not Moving all objects to required storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

We have a lifecycle rule setup on a S3 bucket, to move all object from Standard storage class to Glacier Instant Retrieval storage class after 180 days, this was setup for the Current version.

Here is the Rule:

[image: Lifecycle Rule]

Here is one of the folders within the bucket, with date exceeding 180Days:

[image: Glacier Instant Retrieval Storage class]

Here is another folder within the same bucket, with same date, but no objects where transitioned:

[image: Standard Storage class]

We have waited more than the required 48h to see if this takes effect, but only some of the objects are being moved to the correct storage class, there are no filters setup, so should work for all the objects, but looking at the folders , only some files have transitioned, any idea why, could it be that we need to setup the rule on non-current version also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Transitioning objects using Amazon S3 Lifecycle - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html):

> **Objects smaller than 128 KB** – For the following transitions, Amazon S3 does **not** transition objects that are smaller than 128 KB:
>
> - From the S3 Standard or S3 Standard-IA storage classes to S3 Intelligent-Tiering or S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval.
> - From the S3 Standard storage class to S3 Standard-IA or S3 One Zone-IA.

If you take a close look, **all the objects in the second folder are under 128 KB**. These will *not* be transitions to the Glacier storage class.

Comment: I don't think this is the case.S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval has a minimum billable object size of 128 KB. Smaller objects may be stored but will be charged for 128 KB of storage at the appropriate storage class rate.